# SQL injection with telnet

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, telnet

I'm working on a project for my networking class. I have to build two Ubuntu virtual machines with VirtualBox connected by an internal network: the first one is to be a web server who also has a MySQL server with a database and the second VM I have to use to perform sql injection on the database residing on the server. 
Now, here's my problem. The teacher told us we can't use any php or any other server side language to connect to MySQL or implement input forms that the user can fill to perform the injection but instead told us to use Telnet. How can I connect to MySQL and accept user inputs with telnet so that I can perform the SQL injection with Telnet?

Comment: To me it looks like a communication problem. Are you positively sure that the exercise is defined exactly like this and you didn't confuse anything?

Comment: Isn't the [mysql protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) binary?

Comment: Do you mean execute SQL over a telnet session? SQL Injection is the act of inserting extra SQL commands into a preformed query, usually via an unchecked parameter. This is usually done through form fields or POST/GET parameters over HTTP. Maybe I am missing something, but it doesn't seem clear as to what you are supposed to be doing. Does the professor mean to have you intercept a telnet session via a MITM attack and rewrite SQL commands being transmitted?

Comment: To perform "SQL injection" you need to have a scripted web page with SQL queries in it that can be exploited. Connecting directly to the database server is not a SQL injection exploit, that's a straight up database compromise. `telnet` can be used to make HTTP requests, maybe that's what's being asked here.